# Why is my @State var seemingly automatically getting reset to its initialized value?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I am trying to present a `View` via the `.sheet(isPresented:)` view modifier, the `@State` boolean variable I am using for `isPresented:` only ever needs to be set to `true` for the sheet to correctly show and go away, and this confuses me. I assumed I would have to both set the `@State` variable to `true` and `false` manually, but it seems to automatically go back to `false` after I leave the sheet by tapping out of it.

For example (you can see `managing` initialized to `false`):

```
@State private var managing = false

var body: some View {
  HStack {
    SomeViews()
  }
  .sheet(isPresented: $managing) {
    Manager()
  }
}
```

Then I have some `Button` elsewhere controlling the `managing` variable:

```
Button {
  managing = true
} label: {
  SomeLabel()
}
```

Here is a complete example you can run:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var managing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                managing = true
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            }
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $managing) {
            Text("Manager")
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Why do I only have to set the `managing` var to `true` for the sheet to work?

If the defaulty-nil `onDismiss:` parameter is not passed into `.sheet(isPresented:)`, does the view modifier automatically toggle the passed in `Binding` when dismissed?

Edit: It seems even when passing in an `onDismiss:` closure the sheet will dismiss correctly.

Comment: “does the view modifier automatically toggle the passed in Binding when dismissed?” — yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI sheets/modals manage the state that toggled it automatically. You can see this for yourself by adding an `.onChange` modifier.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var toggle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Toggle Me") {
            self.toggle = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$toggle, content: { Sheet() })
        .onChange(of: self.toggle) { newValue in
            print(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

where `Sheet()` is just some text:

```swift
struct Sheet: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("sheet")
    }
}
```

When you dismiss the sheet, by pulling down on iOS or by tapping outside on iPadOS, you can observe that the `toggle` state will be set to false when the sheet is fully dismissed.

Furthermore, if you choose to dismiss the sheet via a toolbar button, such as through the `dismiss` environment variable, it will also manage your initial state correctly:

```swift
struct Sheet: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("sheet")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Done") {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

You can test both examples to see when and how the state changes for yourself.